# Where is the sidebar in this pen?

Tags: html, css, layout

> How can you fix sidebar issue here:
>   http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ClGcF

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
header {
  background: lightblue;
}
section {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
article {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
aside {
  background: pink;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
header,
article,
section,
.module {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Site</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo molestias ex officia eligendi reiciendis fuga magnam? Ullam ut ab doloremque accusamus iusto aliquam facilis sapiente!</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo molestias ex officia eligendi reiciendis fuga magnam? Ullam ut ab doloremque accusamus iusto aliquam facilis sapiente!</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <div class="module">
      <h3>Module</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio rem ab delectus fugit repellendus perspiciatis dolor consequuntur tenetur voluptatem a vitae odit aspernatur? Voluptas quisquam corporis nostrum aspernatur aliquid harum saepe ab pariatur
        veniam iste ipsam alias nemo voluptatibus doloribus.</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
</main>
```

The goal is to have the sidebar move back to the top.

My confusion:

**Where is the sidebar there inside the pen?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<aside>` is the sidebar part.

In your css:

```
*,*:after,*:before { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

You can read about box-sizing following this link: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Am I Hired?
Accept my answer :P

Comment: Yes, you can join the team in a min ;) (15 minutes accepting time-limit)

Comment: I'm in, 
but I want to work with es6 instead of css :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are telling the program to take up 100% of the pagewidth. If you reduce the two widths to 70% and 20-25%, the sidebar will float right, adjacent to the main content body.

Comment: I thought the same, no the interview test was to check if `box-sizing` was understood by the candidate.

Comment: @ManojKumar In this comment, were you referring to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)? [Irish's link](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) need some **TL;DR** version ;)